# How to select a certain element in CSS by numerical position

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, web

For example:

```
 <ul id="list">
   <li>Item1</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
   <li>Item3</li>
 </ul>
```

I want to select the second li.  Using jQuery for example:

```
$("#list li[num='2']")......
```

Obviously "num=2" isn't the real thing but hopefully you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [nth-child(n)](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector.

Basically you put the number you want where n is, and it will get that element.

```
$('#list li:nth-child(2)')......
```

This gets the 2nd `li` element inside #list

Comment: have an upvote.  Abody was 9 sec before you so I have to give him the points.

Comment: @user974896 Something fun to note is IE8 and down don't support the `nth-child(n)` selector in CSS, however there are similar selectors. the `+` sign means "next sibling" and IE8 supports both that and first-child (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) so you could do #list li:first-child + li. This would achieve the same thing but would also work in IE8. Obviously it has limitations

Answer (score 3):

Can be done like this too:

```
$("#list li:eq(1)")
```

:eq() is zero based index

Answer (score 2):

```
#list li:nth-child(2) {
   ...
}
```

[More info about the `nth-child` selector (as a CSS3 selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child).

[jQuery reference for `nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Comment: Mind that this is a CSS3 selector and does not compute in older browsers if you use it in pure CSS. It will work as a jQuery selector however.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var second_li= $("#list li:nth-child(2)");
```

But nth-child won't work in IE < v9

Comment: It's not supported if it's used as a CSS selector. There's no problem if it's used as a jQuery selector.